# Labelling the dataset : Variable explorer not displaying any variables

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to label my devanagari dataset which I've placed in Documents folder further inside consonants folder which contains 36 different folders each containing specific consonants. **I am not getting any error but Variable explorer is not showing any variables.** Can anybody tell where I am going wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated. The code is as below:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import glob
    import numpy as np
    #%%
    path=glob.glob('./Documents/Trying/ 
    Devanagari_character_dataset/consonants/*/')

    k=0

    label=[]
    img_list=[]
    specific_folders=[]

    for img in path:
    img_list=plt.imread(img)
    file=glob.glob(path[k]+'/*')
    for i, x in file:
    specific_folders=plt.imread(x)
    k +=1
    label.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

To show all variables in the Variable Explorer, you need to go to its *Options* menu (the little cog to its right) and select the option called *Exclude unsupported data types*.